# What is the use of text with colon operator (eg: Test:) in java

Tags: java, syntax

In one of the forum I found below code as a question:

```
public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Hello");
        Test:
        System.out.println("World");
    }
}
```

And asked what would be the result ?

I thought it would be a compile time error, since I have not seen **`Test:`** code in java. 
I was wrong, surprisingly both line is printed after compiling and running above code.

Can any one tell me what is the use of this **`Test:`** kind of code ? And why it is not throwing error ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Text followed by a colon (`:`) is called a [label](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html). It can be used in the context of control structures (such as loops) to `break` to or `continue` at. In this context, although perfectly legal, it's pointless.

Answer (score 5):

The `Test:` text is a label, and is described in [the language specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.7), and are used to `break` or `continue` from inner loops as shown in the following example:

> Unlike C and C++, the Java programming language has no goto statement;
>   identifier statement labels are used with break or continue statements
>   (§14.15, §14.16) appearing anywhere within the labeled statement.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    outerLoop:
    while (true) {
        int i = 0;
        while (true) {
            System.out.println(i++);
            if (i > 5) {
                break outerLoop;
            }
            if (i > 10) {
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Broken inner loop");
    }
    System.out.println("Broken outer loop");
}
```